Car either fires right up or makes no sound at all
@007 Buick Rendezvous, when i turn the key the car either starts right up or makes no sound, by the 3rd try it has been starting but sometimes just fires right up. No issue with lights, radio, or instrument panel.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

The most likely issues that would cause these symptoms -

Starter solenoid contacts are worn.
Starter motor brushes are worn.
Faulty starter relay in the fusebox.
Faulty contacts in the ignition switch.

